# MVVM LIGHT - Message received several times

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

First of all, english is not my native language so I apologize if there are mistakes.

I'm encountering an issue with the messenger of MVVM Light Messenger.
It seems that it fires several times even if I unregister the messenger. There are a lot of post about this on SO but nothing seems to resolve my problem.

All my viewModel are Singleton created by the `ViewModelLocator` and only the `ViewModels` use the Messenger.

I use the registering method with a token, which is the `viewModelName`, and a `ProcessMessage` method to process the message. Every `ViewModel` registers the same way in the constructor and all have a different name:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<SimpleMessage>(this, ViewModelName, ProcessMessage);
```

The SimpleMessage is a simple class with an object and an enum.

When I send message, I always use a token, for example:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(message, ViewModelNameEnum.Home);
```

The message is received by the recipient, but after 2 or 3 received messages, it is triggered several times and the number of times increases for each received message.

I've tried to destroy and recreate ViewModel after use but with no luck. The message will be received several times after 2 or 3 call to the sendMessage method. I've also tried this but again, it's not working as expected:

```
    public static void UnRegisterViewModel<T>(T instance) where T : ViewModelTemplate
    {
        Messenger.Default.Unregister<SimpleMessage>(instance, instance.ViewModelName);
        instance.Cleanup();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Unregister<T>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<T>(true);
    }
```

I've seen that in the Messenger.Default class, there is a private field "_recipientStrictAction" which store the recipients.
There is indeed several times the same token in the list when it fires multiples times.

Is there someone who can explain me what I've done wrong?

Comment: The obvious explanation is you're subscribing several times. Either several in one instance of the viewmodel or once each in several instances of your viewmodel.

Comment: All the viewmodel are Singleton. I register each time I destroy then recreates viewModel: I unregister the recipient of the Messenger before unregistering it from the SimpleIOC. Then I register the new instance in the SimpleIOC and finally in the Messenger (in the constructor).  The unregister method should... unregister...

Comment: Could you please set a breakpoint at the beginning of the method `UnRegisterViewModel<T>` and count how often it is called, to validate the suggestion from @Andy ?

Comment: @RenéCarannante I've tested it. There is no problem on that side.  The method is called when necessary.